# Why can't I install numpy on python 3 in visual studio code

Tags: python, numpy, visual-studio-code

I don't know why it doesn't work, when I run the command `pip install numpy` in the terminal in visual studio this error gets produced:

```
pip : The term 'pip' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the
 name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ pip install numpy
+ ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (pip:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Please help

Comment: try ```python -m pip``` instead of ```pip``` or ```pip3``` if it seems to work for you.

Comment: Unfortunetly that produces this error:python : The term 'python' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling 
of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ python -m pip
+ ~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (python:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Comment: can you run it via cmd? or what command do you run to initiate python in VSCode?

Comment: Via the external command terminal? It says: 'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: then python or pip are not on your PATH (environment variable)

Comment: If you can't run pip or pip3 from any directory on your machine, it isn't installed correctly.  You need to check your installation, and possibly re-install.  If you need to re-install, removing all of your python related stuff first is a good idea.

Comment: I solved it, I had to write "py -m pip install numpy". I don't know why the regular pip install didn't work though.